# Determining matrix M from $Mx_1 = b_1$ & $Mx_2 = b_2$, where $x_1, x_2, b_1, b_2$ vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have 4 vectors in the plane, $x_1$ and $x_2$, $b_1$ and $b_2$, and I'm told that there is a matrix $M$ such that $Mx_1 = b_1$ and $Mx_2 = b_2$.

If I have a vector $x_3$, how do I determine $Mx_3$? I know I'm supposed to find out what $M$ is, and then apply it to $x_3$, but how do I do this? Thanks.

Comment: You cant do it unless $x_1,x_2$ are lineary independent. If they are then $x_3=ax_1+bx_2$ and then $$Mx_3=aMx_1+bMx_2.$$

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to find $M$ in order to find $Mx_3.$ for example if $x_3 = 2x_1,$ then $Mx_3 = 2Mx_1 = 2b_1$ what you need to find are the components $\alpha_1, \alpha_2$ so that $x_3 = \alpha_1x_1 + \alpha_2 x_2.$  then $Mx_3 = \alpha_1b_1 + \alpha_2 b_2.$